Repeated 'chtex 44: User Regex' warnings for any reference
Sorry if this is an old and previously-covered issue, but I couldn't find anything about it on this website... or at least, I wasn't able to figure out if/how those solutions apply to my problem.
Here is a stripped down version of the base document:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % Set 1-inch margins on all sides
\usepackage{amsmath} % For math formatting
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\parskip=1em
\begin{document}

\title{Math v1.0}
\author{Oh Shit, Gorillas!, Ph.Ds.}
\maketitle
\sloppy
\section*{Introduction}
This document covers the math used in my program.

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\include{raw.tex}
\include{outliers.tex}
\include{volumes.tex}
\include{xcals.tex}
\include{recommendations.tex}

\end{document}

My problem is that whenever I reference an internal section of this document, I get a warning. For example, I'll label the outliers section sec:outliers:
\section{Outlier Detection and Filtering}\label{sec:outliers}
Once all intensity data have been checked for outliers and all fitted intensities $y_0$ have been determined, we proceed with checking for outliers among analyses in the sequence. Two outlier detection methods are provided: automatic and manual.

Analyses flagged as outliers are excluded from all further calculations.

Then, when I go to reference that section, either within outliers.tex or in one of the other sections, I see:

Strangely enough, I've discovered that if I change the text section to sec, e.g. sec~\ref{sec:outliers}, the warning goes away... however, while the shorthand 'sec' works fine in parenthesis, I'd prefer to reference "section x.x" in the text without receiving this warning.
I've also tried changing the label from sec:outliers to section:outliers, but this doesn't remove the warning when referencing a 'section' rather than a 'sec'.

In the future, just showing "User Regex" isn't enough to tell what it's actually complaining about since there can be any number of user specified warnings.  However, in this case, it's probably due to a default warning that says you should capitalize Section when used in this way, namely Section~\ref{sec:outliers}.
If you don't like that warning you can change the chktexrc file for ChkTeX and remove it or comment it out.  I'm not sure what editor/plugin you use or how easy they make it to change, but if you're interested you can check the manual which should have enough information on how to override it for your operating system.  If it doesn't answer your questions feel free to hit me up with whatever questions you have and I might be able to improve the documentation.

I was finally able to fix this using cleverref
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\crefname{section}{Section}{Sections}
\crefname{subsection}{Section}{Sections}
\crefname{subsubsection}{Section}{Sections}
\crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equations}

\include{outliers.tex}

Test text to reference \cref{sec:outliers}.

\end{document}

generates the proper text with no warning

Minimal example:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{sec:test}

We see in section~\ref{sec:test} that \dots

\end{document}

The response of chktex when processing this small document is
ChkTeX v1.7.8 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T. Berger Thielemann.
Compiled with POSIX extended regex support.
chktex: WARNING -- Compilation of regular expression \[(?![^\]\[{}]*{(?![^\]\[{}]*}))[^\]]*\[ failed with error repetition-operator operand invalid.

Warning 44 in gorilla.tex line 7: User Regex: 1:Capitalize before references.
We see in section~\ref{sec:test} that \dots
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
No errors printed; One warning printed; No user suppressed warnings; No line suppressed warnings.
See the manual for how to suppress some or all of these warnings/errors.
The manual is available by running `texdoc chktex` or at https://www.nongnu.org/chktex/ChkTeX.pdf

There are two issues here: one is that somehow chktex uses a nonconforming regular expression format and this issue should be solved by the maintainers.
The second issue is about a warning about a stylistic decision. Possibly some style manual mandates that “section” should be capitalized, but it's an author's decision nonetheless. You solve this by calling
chktex -n44 <filename>

If I run this on the example file, I get
ChkTeX v1.7.8 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T. Berger Thielemann.
Compiled with POSIX extended regex support.
No errors printed; No warnings printed; No user suppressed warnings; No line suppressed warnings.

